# Why we have protected access specifier in java?

Tags: java, oop, protected

What is the example situation where protected is preferred, but not public?
Can someone can elaborate it with example?
I have already seen the chat for public, private and protected ([see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)).

Comment: Private means only your class can use it.  Protected means you and your children can use it.  This is useful when you want to hide something from general use, but need to give subclasses more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A primary use of `protected` is cases where a subclass overrides a method that provides some internal details that you don't want to expose to the outside classes. Consider a class like

```
class BaseAlgorithm {
     run() {
        commonStepOne();
        subclassSpecificStepTwo();
     }

     protected abstract subclassSpecificStepTwo();
}
```

No one should be calling `subclassSpecificStepTwo`, so it wouldn't make sense to have it public.

Comment: ... but keep in mind that `protected` will also be accessible from other classes within the same package.

Comment: Correct, there is no modifier that just allows access by the subclasses, so yes, classes in the same package could call this. But not much you can do about it in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, `protected` means that the method (for example) will be accessible only within the subclasses and the package in which it's defined.

```
Modifier    | Class | Package | Subclass | World
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
protected   |  ✔    |    ✔    |    ✔     |   ✘
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
```

More info:

- [What's the difference between public, defaul, protected and private ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Answer (score 0):

if a method is protected then it  can be accessed within the same package or from the subclass of different package

Have a look at the [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 0):

Question is about usage and use case, so, I have an example.

Consider an **abstract** class, that will demand it subclass to implement some method, that is not a part of it's public API, and used only inside this class or it's subclasses.

We can't use private modifier, we don't want to make this method public.

So, `protected` keyword make our API clear, and prevent incapsulation break.

Do you need code example?

Answer (score 0):

All these `private, public, protected or no-access modifiers(default)` are just a concept to develop to do coding in well organize manner.

You can find some good information from [here](http://javapapers.com/core-java/access-modifiers-in-java-explain/). The answer you are looking is there.

**But** there is no such protection, hidden information using any of these modifiers in `Java`

Consider following code

```
public class ProtectedPrivacy{

 private String getInfo1(){
 return "private"; 
 }

 protected String getInfo2(){
 return "protected"; 
 }

 String getInfo3(){
 return "default"; 
 }

 public String getInfo4(){
 return "public"; 
 }
}
```

Any access level you can violate as follows

```
public class BreakModifires{

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   ProtectedPrivacy protectedPrivacy = new ProtectedPrivacy();
   Method method = protectedPrivacy.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getInfo*", null);
   method.setAccessible(true);
   Object result = method.invoke(protectedPrivacy);
   System.out.println(result.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `public` class member makes a promise *to the entire universe* on behalf of *all possible future derivatives and sub-derivatives of a class* that all derivatives of that class will support a particular functionality a certain way.

A `protected` protected member makes a promise on behalf of *itself only*, to any classes that derive from it, that it will support a particular functionality a certain way; derivatives of that class are free to decide whether or not they wish to take advantage of that functionality, or provide any public methods which would use it.

The reason that `public` promises are binding on subclasses and `protected` ones are not is that if a subclasses were not bound by their parents' public promises, there would be no way for code that had a reference to an `Animal` could safely call `MakeNoise` on it without knowing whether it was a type which wasn't required to have a `MakeNoise` member.  By contrast, if a class has a protected member, the only way that member can be called is via `super`.  If `Animal` implemented a protected `DetectSmells` member and `Cat` supported it but `Fish` did not, the fact that `Fish` doesn't support that method wouldn't affect a `SiameseCat`'s ability to call `super.DetectSmells()`, *since it knows `super` is a `Cat` and not a `Fish`*.